# Make a standard PDF fillable

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to transform a standard PDF into a fillable one.
My original PDF contains forms and text area to be filled.
Moreover, is it possible to add a "send-by-mail" button at the botton of the PDF ?

I would prefer ubuntu-compatible opensource tools,
But I will go for windows if needed.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use free/open source Dhek template editor, to define in a separate file (in JSON format) the areas (bounds, and related properties) where you want to write/fill dynamic data  at some point with extra data over any existing PDF.

*Example of JSON template format: (see [documentation](https://github.com/applicius/dhek#integration))*

```
{
  "pages": [
    { /* mappings for first page, index 0 */
    "areas": [
      { /* first area of first page */
        "type": "text"/* or "checkbox"*/
        "height": 10.23/* pt */,
        "width": 23.456,
        "x": 0.1234/* pt */,
        "y": 2.45,
        "name": "Field name"
      }
      /* , other areas ... */
    }
    /* , other pages ... */ 
  ]
}
```

You can have a look at it at the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/applicius/dhek) with [binary releases](http://go.applidok.com/en/download.gz.html) available for Windows 7+ and Mac OS X 10.9+ .

An integration example in PHP using FPDF library is [available online](https://github.com/applicius/dhek#php-integration).

Answer (score 0):

That's a case for Acrobat (Standard would work, but Pro is preferrable).

You may be quite successful by using the field recognition function in Acrobat, otherwise, you will add the fields manually in the Form Edit mode.